# Finding moment generating function of this r.v. with double exponential dist

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

[image]

So in the above question, we can say the moment generating function is $$m_x(t) = \frac{1}{2}\theta\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx-\theta |x|} dx$$

Now, as the hint suggests, we can split the integral into two parts, $\int_0^\infty$ and $\int^0_{-\infty}$, but I can't figure out to integrate that function. Any help? Thanks!

Comment: If $x>0$ then $|x|=x$ and $tx-\theta|x|=tx-\theta x=(t-\theta)x$. I think you can do the rest.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Ok, thanks! I've managed to get the desired function. Do you agree that $|t|<\theta$ is the values of t that this function is defined upon?

Comment: Yes, you got it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the moment generating function of the Laplace distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101653/what-is-the-moment-generating-function-of-the-laplace-distribution)